# How to take single database backup using mysqlbackup command in Mysql 8.0.18 version DB

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysql-8.0

I have a mysql instance(8.0.18-commercial MySQL enterprise server) with 8 databases in it and out of those I only need to take the backup of DB named 'Test1'.

Please note that its 300 GB sized DB and I want to take backup and restore it using mysqlbackup command. Is there any option for that, please guide me.

Comment: Seems to be [mysqlback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.1/en/backup-partial-options.html) options to handle a single DB. Recommend testing on a smaller database and then try on your larger database restoring to a new server.

Comment: Did you try `--databases=` option? 

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-enterprise-backup-3.5-en/mysqlbackup.usage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create the backup using the `--tts` option, when restoring your instance you can include/exclude selected tables. A whole database is included/excluded by selecting all of its tables with `--include/exclude="^databasename\."`

The MySQL official documentation explains it very well:

- TLR: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/restore.partial.html
- Restoring a backup created with "tts" option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/restore-use-tts.html

Hope it helps.